# some kelobytes read from socket but notwrite to the file

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I am at the server side, and receive Image as binary stream from a client, 
the server Detect that we deal with image and the size in bytes arrived to the server via previous message from the client!

the server have a size of the file supposed to read, and stream...Eter to while loop... read from the Client Stream, and immediately write to the file, and reset the buffer to read
Everything Work wellm until Some kilobytes before the end of the file some kilobytes don't writen to the file... I get smaller file on the server library... (and I can see the image with small gray row at the bottom.

here the my attempt :

```
               /*loop*/  while (bytesRemaining!=0)  {
                 try {
                   // read from client  
                   baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                   bytesRemaining = sizeToread - readtotal;     
                   bytesRead = OIS.read(aByte, 0, bytesRemaining);
                  readtotal+=bytesRead;
                   System.out.println(     ", Remaining: "    +bytesRemaining);
                   System.out.println("read at oce: "+bytesRead) ;
                    System.out.println(++i+") have Read: "+ readtotal+", aByte:"+aByte[i-1]);


                   try {
                     baos.write(aByte); // write first byte to buffer

                     try{
                     bos.write(baos.toByteArray(),0,bytesRead);
                     }catch (IOException s){  System.out.println("not write to file"+s);}

          baos.reset();

                //     bos.flush();

                 } catch (IOException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(ThrdConv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                   System.out.println("baos.write(aByte); error  = "+ex );
                 }
                //  if (!(OIS.available()> 0))break; // until uavailabil stream
                 }      catch (EOFException eoff) {
   Logger.getLogger(ThrdConv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, eoff);
   System.out.println("Line 601 error= "+eoff );
    break;
   } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ThrdConv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    System.out.println("Line 612,613 error= "+ex );
                 }


            } //loop End ///////////////////////////////////////////
```

### note:file  size: 474591

My prints gives:

```
...
...
...
458) have Read: 468992, aByte:52
, Remaining: 5599
read at oce: 1024
459) have Read: 470016, aByte:59
, Remaining: 4575
read at oce: 1024
460) have Read: 471040, aByte:-117
, Remaining: 3551
read at oce: 1024
461) have Read: 472064, aByte:-110
, Remaining: 2527
read at oce: 1024
462) have Read: 473088, aByte:-8
, Remaining: 1503
read at oce: 1024
463) have Read: 474112, aByte:-124
, Remaining: 479
read at oce: 479
464) have Read: 474591, aByte:125
, Remaining: 0
read at oce: 0
465) have Read: 474591, aByte:30
realfile: C:\wamp\www\RandomSendServer\images\1384252358431.jpg
have Read: 474591 !!!
URL sent Back
```

I get file with size 466944 istead of: 474591 ....
any help

**update**

```
 according to answer 1 I make this change... my loop now looks:
                while ((bytesRead = OIS.read(aByte))>1)
 { bos.write(aByte,0,bytesRead);
 i+=bytesRead;
    System.out.println(bytesRead+" "+i);                 
 }
```

the print:

total read: 474591
realfile: C:\wamp\www\RandomSendServer\images\1384262866220.jpg
URL sent

**but the same problem still**
the loop tell it read all the 474,591  ... but when I check the file its size is: 466,944

### **Final Solution**

```
   while( ( bytesRead = OIS.read(aByte))>0)
                     { 
     fos.write(aByte,0,bytesRead);
     i+=bytesRead; // i is a counter
    if(i==sizeToread) break; // force to stop when read all the bytes in the file!
    }
```

Comment: may I know why the -1 ???

Comment: May the person who vote me down explain why???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This frightful code is so riddled with errors and misconceptions and pointless excresences that your best course is just to throw it away. The canonical way to copy streams in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
     out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Note that you don't need any `ByteArrayInput/OutputStreams` at all, but you do need to process the result returned by `read()`. And keep it simple. The task isn't nearly as difficult as you've made it.

EDIT You didn't specify your peer wasn't closing the connection after sending the file, which changes things. Your 'final solution' won't work. It will usually over-run the length. You need to change the read call as follows:

```
while (i < sizeToRead && (count = in.read(buffer, 0, sizeToRead-i > buffer.length ? buffer.length : (int)(sizeToRead-i))) > 0)
```

and remove the inner test.

Comment: That suggests you aren't closing the file.

Comment: I dont know why the loop condition does't stop it, so the solution is above in new update, thank EJP for the help

Comment: My solution Works fine but your solution  "guarantee" not to fail in any problem with the sizes, thumb up, Thank you very much

Comment: In other words yours doesn't work except in special cases where the sizes work out evenly.